# Getting JS Errors When Using jQuery in Cognos Report

Tags: jquery, cognos, cognos-8

I am using Cognos 8.3 and am trying to incorporate jquery/jquery ui into one of my existing reports.  I have an HTML block on the page with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ABC/javascript/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ABC/javascript/other_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

The other_script.js is just a file where we have set a couple of variables.  When I run the report, I get a client-side exception stating

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I have tracked the exception to be from PRMTcompiled.js (built in script in Cognos).  I have looked online and have yet to find anything regarding this error.  I have seen examples where people are successful at integrating the library with Cognos by using jQuery instead of $, but nothing that is my issue.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did your code block break when posting your example script?  I see nothing in your last script block.

Comment: Same here.. Dont know whats wrong with cognos javascripts